# Send url seed to EC2 instances using Python

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, scrapy

I'm building a web crawler using EC2 in python. I have a master instance and a couple of slave instance. The master instance is responsible of collecting urls need to be scraped and send them to slave consistently. I have two question:

1. is there a queue-like data base which can store urls for each instance? Each instance will have a DB for storing urls.
2. how could I send urls from master instance to slave instance?
   Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a queue messaging service like [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/), [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [RestMQ](http://restmq.com/) (which is based on Redis).

The interfaces to each of these pieces of software will be different, but generally on your server you do will do something like:

```
q = SomeQueueClass.connect('some.ip.address.0')
q.push('http://someurl.com')
```

And then on each client you will do

```
q = SomeQueueClass.connect('some.ip.address.0')
url = q.pop()
```

and maybe

```
q.done(url)
```

The Queue service will handle preventing race conditions, ensuring messages are persistent, and ensuring messages are delivered.

Comment: Thanks. It sounds either of them can do the work, which api is most convenient to use?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think I've only used RabbitMQ. You should research other alternative options and find out what's best for your situation.

Comment: I just discovered amazon sqs. Are the APIs you listed more suitable than sqs?

Comment: The apps I listed share the same basic trade-off profile as other apps you administer yourself when compared to hosted Amazon services. I doubt for your modest needs that any framework or application is going to be more or less suited, quite frankly